# $cluetip is undefined: why?

Tags: jquery, cluetip

When I postload cluetip (i.e. grab it with ajax and then append a script tag to body), I get the following javascript error: $cluetip is undefined. However, everything still works. Any idea why?

The postload script is well-tested and does not break anything else. I have confirmed that the scripts are loading in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and here is how I finally resolved it (i.e., no more `$cluetip` undefined error msg).

First, here is my scenario which may be similar to yours. On the page, I have a

```
<div id="sel_area"></div>
```

It is empty and the idea is to employ jquery/ajax to dynamically generate the desired `<select><option>...</option>...</select>` HTML code to insert into the `#sel_area` above like so

```
$('#sel_area').html(data);
```

where data is the generated HTML `select` tag.

However, I think my problem is because I was not retuning the dynamically generated data result in JSON or in XML format and then processing it accordingly.  Instead, I was lazily returning the result as-is as ordinary text/html. When I kept getting the `$cluetip` is undefined error no matter what I tried, I decided to use `alert(data)` to see was was being returned. Alas, there I saw with my own eyes that data was not just only what I had echoed but it had the entire html page appended to it!  The solution was then clear to me. Without giving in to returning data in XML or JSON protocol, I made the following minor changes to solve the problem:

The change at the remote script that generates the `<select>` tag. The last last was

```
echo "$select_tag";
```

I changed this to

```
echo "$select_tag~";
```

That is, I appended a trailing ~ (tilde) to serve as a separator between my `select_tag` string output and the HTML page that I now knew would be appended whether I liked it or not.

The change in the jQuery/AJAX method.

I replaced the line

```
$('#sel_area').html(data);
```

with the following lines:

```
data_list = data.split('~');
$('#sel_area').html(data_list[0]);
```

There you have it. That does the trick. The split method enabled me to detach my desired `select_tag` from data easily because I had wisely inserted ~ (tilde) to serve as my field separator which I knew was neither part of the `select_tag` result nor the HTML page to be appended by the system.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically-loaded scripts are not available immediately. You have to wait for the script to completely load, which is a problem more complicated than one might imagine.

Comment: is there a jquery plugin or something to handle this? I had rolled my own postload script.

Comment: Also-- the $cluetip var is only referenced within the cluetip js itself. Not externally. Does your answer still apply?

Comment: Well, are you 100% sure that the script is successfully loading? You may want to try the Chrome console's "Network" tab, or in Firefox the "Tamper Data" plugin, to make sure that the HTTP requests that you think are fetching the library actually work. Of course, if the "$cluetip" reference is inside the library, and it's failing, then that could mean that either your library is corrupted or else that it has unsatisfied external dependencies.

Comment: I am sure that it is loading because the tooltips actually work. The documentation indicates that there are no dependencies.

Comment: BTW it works fine when I load the js normally. It is only when I postload that the error arises.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "postload"?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know cluetip, and it may be a typo, but `$cluetip` won't be defined, `$.cluetip` (note the "**.**") should be.

A quick look at the docs seems to make me think that cluetip is a function that must be called on some element i.e. `$('#somediv').cluetip(...)`. If you want global defaults you have `$.cluetip.setup(...)`, but either way, it won't define `$cluetip`, just `$.cluetip`.